# Define and insert Thymeleaf fragments in TEXT templates

Tags: thymeleaf

I'm trying to create email templates in both plain text and HTML with Thymeleaf. Because I don't want to duplicate the common parts I want to define these parts separately and insert them into the more specific templates.

It works for HTML, but for plain text variables in the common parts are not replaced:

**HTML**

- common.html

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
      <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      </head>
      <body>
          <div th:fragment="header">
              <p>
                  Hello, [( ${name} )]
              </p>
          </div>
          <div th:fragment="footer">
              <p>
                  Bye.
              </p>
          </div>
      </body>
  </html>
  ```
- specific.html

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
      <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      </head>
      <body>
          <div th:replace="html/common::header"></div>
          <p>
              <a th:href="${myLink}">[( ${myLink} )]</a>
          </p>
          <div th:replace="html/common::footer"></div>
      </body>
  </html>
  ```

**Plain text**

- header.txt

  ```
  Hello ${name}
  ```
- footer.txt

  ```
  Bye
  ```
- specific.txt

  ```
  [( ~{text/header} )]
  [( ${myLink} )]
  [( ~{text/footer} )]
  ```

**Result**

It all works well for HTML but for the plain text version the `${name}` variable from the inserted `header.txt` template is not replaced:

```
Hello, [#th:block th:utext="${name}"][/th:block]

    http://example.com

Bye.
```

The HTML result looks correct:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p>
                Hello, name-value
            </p>
        </div>
        <p>
            <a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a>
        </p>
        <div>
            <p>
                Bye.
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**My questions**

- Is there an elegant solution for the plain text version?
- Is there a way to define and use fragments also for textual Thymeleaf templates?
- Any general recommendations, as I'm only starting to use Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Variables in the Plain Text Version

For the plain text issue, you can use the `[#th:block]` syntax.

Specifically, instead of using this in your `specific.txt`:

```
[( ~{text/header} )]
```

you can use this:

```
[#th:block th:replace="text/header"][/th:block]
```

Also, in the `header.txt` file, instead of using this:

```
Hello ${name}
```

you need to use this:

```
Hello [( ${name} )]
```

This is expression inlining - which you have already used - and is presented [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#expression-inlining), for reference.

Some additional examples of the `[#th:block]` syntax are presented [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#textual-syntax).

### Defining and Using Fragments for Text

You might think that the `[#th:block]` syntax would now allow us to use fragments, in a similar way to the HTML approach. For example, something like this:

```
DOES NOT WORK:
[#th:block th:replace="text/common :: header"][/th:block]
```

together with a `common.txt` fragment like this:

```
ALSO DOES NOT WORK:
[#th:block th:fragment="header"]
Hello, [( ${name} )]
[/th:block]
```

If you try this, you will get the following error:

> *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Template selectors cannot be specified for a template using a TEXT template mode: template insertion operations must be always performed on whole template files, not fragments*

### General Comments

The only other thing I would mention here, if you have not already seen or used it, is [parameterized fragments](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#parameterizable-fragment-signatures). They can make HTML fragments more flexible and re-usable.