# How to use Thymeleaf layout dialect with Textual Syntax?

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I'm trying to use the `layout:decorate` directive with a text file (plain text email header/footer)

Template begin called:

```
[# layout:decorate="~{email/plainPart}" th:with="subject=${subject}" ]
[# layout:fragment="content"]
Thanks for ordering [( ${orderDetail} )].
[/]
[/]
```

Layout template:

```
Subject: [( ${subject} )]
[# layout:fragment="content"][/]
```

The temple renders fine, and without any errors, but I'm not seeing any of the layout template (Subject, for example).

Answer (score 0):

I've been unable to get `layout:decorate` to work. But based on a Stack Overflow [answer about th:replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61406388/define-and-insert-thymeleaf-fragments-in-text-templates), I've been able to come up with a sort of solution:

Template:

```
[#th:block th:replace="email/plainPart.txt"][/th:block]

Thanks for ordering [( ${orderDetail} )].
```

plainPart.txt:

```
[( ${subject} )]
```